# Server 2012 new AD domain next to existing SBS domain

Tags: active-directory

I've got the following scenario.

- Server 2003 SBS with an active directory domain: ***COMPANY.LOCAL***
- Server 2012 Standard 2012 with a workgroup: ***WORKGROUP***
- No computers in the company are  part of the existing SBS domain (***COMPANY.LOCAL***)

  - We have some users who access shares on the SBS server using local admin account.

I would like to create a new domain on the 2012 server without joining it to the existing SBS domain (***COMPANY.LOCAL***)  or  migrate any user or groups.

Would it be possible to install AD services onto the 2012 server and create a domain called: ***ad.company.co.uk***?

***One word of warning on this***

When you get to the point of choosing your netbios name, you won't be able to choose ***COMPANY*** as this will already be taken by your SBS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that should be absolutely fine, you can have multiple domains on the same network without any issues.

You may want to take care with your DHCP/DNS configuration so that domain name resolution works correctly but without any more details on what you plan to do with the domain its hard to give any more concrete advice